# HTML Bold Text on Image hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, this is my Test HTML-Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>TEST</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:22px;color: #FFFFFF;background-color: #000000;}
.ntable {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #000000;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#000000; margin-left:20px;}
.ntabletd {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:16px;border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;}
.ntablett {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:20px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;background-color:#000000;font-weight:bold;color:white;}
.ntable td:hover {font-weight: bold;}
.ntitle {font-family: Papyrus;font-size: 24px;padding: 8px;background-color: #000000;font-weight: bold;color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: underline;}
.ttl2 {text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:#555555;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 18%" align="left" class="ntable" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <th class="ntitle" style="width: 190px">Naviagtion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb">
        <td onmousedown="return false;" name="home" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="home.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Home<span style="margin-left:46px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Menu principal</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb2">
        <td onmousedown="return false;" name="gallerie" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="gallerie.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Galerien<span style="margin-left:28px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Galeries</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb3">
        <td onmousedown="return false;" name="gaestebuch" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="gaestebuch.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">G&auml;stebuch<span style="margin-left:11px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Livre d'Or</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb4">
        <td onmousedown="return false;" name="links" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="links.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">Links<span style="margin-left:51px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Liens</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb5">
        <td onmousedown="return false;" name="impressum" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="impressum.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">Impressum<span style="margin-left:19px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Contact</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>




<table style="margin-top:100px; width: 481px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="363px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/np8rxs113nz.png" width="481" /></td>
        <td rowspan="7"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="633px" name="changer" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png" width="363px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><a href="home.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/5286mnzt75n2.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png', b.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="home.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><a href="gallerie.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/kxg6kzelggm.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png', b2.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb2.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><a href="gaestebuch.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/z9xewd21v4u.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png', bb3.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb3.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><a href="links.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/tcuzr5l81u2a.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png', bb5.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb5.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><a href="impressum.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/yrcz87mzezjk.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png', bb4.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb4.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 485px"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="120px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ebr7b6nfhle.png" width="481px" /></td>
    </tr>

</body>

</html>
```

You can see, on the left table its no problem to hover the text to bold. But what I want is, that you can move in the picture on the right side. So when your on the first "frame" the text "Home" get bold. And on the second "frame" the text "Galierien" get bold.

I tried so many things now. I can do it problemless with other pictures, but not whit the these here. Hope some one can help me, I searched everywhere!

Oh, and sorry for my bad english, im Swiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID the menu a to get bold, eg. `id="home"`.
Then, add following code:

To `onmouseover`:

```
document.getElementById('home').style.fontWeight='bold';
```

To `onmouseout`:

```
document.getElementById('home').style.fontWeight='normal';
```

Below I attach example with made "to work" the "home" link, rest is for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>TEST</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:22px;color: #FFFFFF;background-color: #000000;}
.ntable {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #000000;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#000000; margin-left:20px;}
.ntabletd {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:16px;border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;}
.ntablett {font-family: Papyrus;font-size:20px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;background-color:#000000;font-weight:bold;color:white;}
.ntable td:hover {font-weight: bold;}
.ntitle {font-family: Papyrus;font-size: 24px;padding: 8px;background-color: #000000;font-weight: bold;color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: underline;}
.ttl2 {text-align:center;font-size:20px;color:#555555;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 18%" align="left" class="ntable" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
    <th class="ntitle" style="width: 190px">Naviagtion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb">
    <td onmousedown="return false;" name="home" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'" style="width: 300px"><a id="home" href="home.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Home<span style="margin-left:46px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Menu principal</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb2">
    <td onmousedown="return false;" name="gallerie" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="gallerie.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Galerien<span style="margin-left:28px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Galeries</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb3">
    <td onmousedown="return false;" name="gaestebuch" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="gaestebuch.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">G&auml;stebuch<span style="margin-left:11px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Livre d'Or</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb4">
    <td onmousedown="return false;" name="links" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="links.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">Links<span style="margin-left:51px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Liens</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bb5">
    <td onmousedown="return false;" name="impressum" class="ntabletd" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png'" onmouseout="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png'" style="width: 300px"><a href="impressum.html" style="text-decoration: none;color:white">Impressum<span style="margin-left:19px;">|</span><span style="margin-left:10px;">Contact</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>




<table style="margin-top:100px; width: 481px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="363px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/np8rxs113nz.png" width="481" /></td>
    <td rowspan="7"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="633px" name="changer" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png" width="363px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><a href="home.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/5286mnzt75n2.png" width="481px" onmouseover="document.getElementById('home').style.fontWeight='bold'; changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png', b.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('home').style.fontWeight='normal'; home.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ycgxxuzcxnaf.png'"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><a href="gallerie.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/kxg6kzelggm.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png', b2.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb2.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/lscr4s5jkoqx.png'"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><a href="gaestebuch.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/z9xewd21v4u.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png', bb3.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb3.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/oi52nbegnx7.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><a href="links.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/tcuzr5l81u2a.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png', bb5.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb5.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/frttgb5tx3aa.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><a href="impressum.html"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="30px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/yrcz87mzezjk.png" width="481px" onmouseover="changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png', bb4.fontWeight='bold'" onmouseout="bb4.fontWeight='normal', changer.src='http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/v355b61s29yw.png';"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 485px"><img onmousedown="return false;" alt="" height="120px" src="http://www7.pic-upload.de/05.04.14/ebr7b6nfhle.png" width="481px" /></td>
    </tr>

</body>

</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot! Problem was, i named the td's and dev's and everything, but not the a.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a working JSFiddle of the above example. Your code is quite a mess. You should also use div's instead of tables for menus. Spend some time with CSS - it'll pay off in the long run. In addition, use CSS hover effects when possible and avoid inline javascript.

First of all there are a few errors in your code. Look at the chrome developer tools console window (press F12).

- Your second table tag hasn't been closed
- changer is not defined anywhere

One you fix this problem, it is likely that your issues will go away. However, verify that with chrome dev tools or post a working fiddle (as in one that doesn't have errors).

Comment: Yeah I know it has a lot of fail codes inside. But this was just a test page. My original code is fine :).